# Running my Router from an inline charger

Tags: electrical

I have a router installed at home that runs from mains power. the transformer plug shows as 0.7 amps.
I want to by an in-line battery pack/ups that can run the router when we have load-shedding for about 3 hours, then the in line battery must charge itself from the 220v mains.

What in-line capacity must I buy?  10000mAh or 20000mAh or even bigger?

Please help

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are talking about a network router or a wood router? A network router doesn't need anywhere near that much capacity.

Comment: get a  cheap 10AH; it's overkill, but the under-draining will benefit it's longevity.

Answer (score 4):

### The first law of battery operation is *conserve FIRST*

It is far, far cheaper to buy an efficient appliance than **buy large quantities of batteries** to power an inefficient one.

Also, under "conservation", avoid double conversions. Running a 12 volt battery to an inverter to make 230V to run a wall-wart power supply to *go back to* 12 volts DC... that's just dumb and wasteful. It also adds failure points that don't need to exist.

0.7 amps at 240V is an outrageous amount of power for a router.  Get a router with two characteristics:

- It is far more efficient energy-wise.
- it uses a "wall wart" power supply **that actually outputs 12 volts DC**.

### Run the router *directly* off the battery

Because we have selected a router which natively requires 12 volts DC, we can run this Directly Off a 12 volt battery.  So there are 2 connections to be made.  First, a cord connection is made from battery terminals to router.  Thus the router is running on battery.  Second, a battery charger plugs into AC mains and also attaches to the battery terminals.

When AC power is available, the battery charger is both charging the battery and powering the router.  Some of its output is passing through to power the router and the rest charges the battery.

During grid-down times, the router simply runs off the battery. This *just happens* passively - nothing special is needed.

Answer (score 3):

It's just math. 700 milliAmperes x 3 hours = 2100 mAh, *though you don't specify if that's the input, the rated output, or the actual amount your device uses, which may be less than the rated output. If it's the input at 220V the math alters drastically depending what the unspecified output voltage is.*

Depending on battery chemistry, you may want that to be 30% or less of the battery nominal capacity for longer life. 7000 mAh would do that.

Cheap lead-acid **hate** deep discharge and die young if they have to go below 50% state of charge. Expensive lithium ion is much more reasonable about using more of the nameplate capacity without major issues.

Answer (score 0):

The larger the capacity, the longer it will run. If the transformer is rated to provide 0.7 A, then the router is drawing less than 0.7 A, so (as the other answer states) you can easily calculate how much capacity you need to run the router for 3 hours.

But what happens when the power comes back on after the battery is discharged? The 0.7A the transformer is rated for is possibly not sufficient to power both the router as well as charge the battery unless the load is carefully managed.

Why not just buy a mains-powered UPS and plug the router's transformer into that? I expect you will not be able to duplicate the performance and durability of a commercially-produced UPS for less cost by building it yourself.

Comment: Real world example, I have a APC Back UPS-600 (600VA battery backup) with a SB Modem, another modem for phone, Netgear R8000 Router, Netgear 8 port switch, and a Raspberry Pi 3B+.  With the data port connected to the Pi, I can see a 50 minute outage in the Pis logs where the UPS lasted at least that long.  I'm sure it could handle less for much longer.

Comment: Based on *then the in line battery must charge itself from the 220v mains.*, I think OP already intends to use a regular line-voltage UPS.